# Реально ли процедурно генерировать "connected" текстуры?

Tags: разработка-игр, текстура, процедурная-генерация

Скажем, есть клетки (n)x(n) пикселей. Изначально хотел генерировать для них текстуры каким-нибудь шумовым алгоритмом, но возникла необходимость сделать соединённые текстуры, это когда одна клетка видоизменяется в зависимости от соседней клетки, контактирует с ней. Вопрос в заголовке.

*P.S. "connected" потому что я вообще не представляю как правильно это назвать, в гугле пусто. Поправьте, если есть соответствующий термин.*

Answer (score 2):

Конечно реально! Они также называются *tileable* и *seamless* текстуры.

А - можете сделать текстуру размером 2n и плавно смешивать переход.

Б - многие алгоритмы поддерживают генерацию connected результатов.

Пример - https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/23625/how-do-you-generate-tileable-perlin-noise